# Deleting file from FTP in C#

Tags: c#, .net, ftp, webclient, delete-file

My program can upload files into an FTP server using this code:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(ftpUsername, ftpPassword);
client.BaseAddress = ftpServer;
client.UploadFile(fileToUpload, WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile, fileName);
```

Right now I need to delete some files and I can't do that right. What should I use instead of

```
client.UploadFile(fileToUpload, WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile, fileName);
```

Answer (score 52):

You'll need to use the [FtpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.aspx) class to do that one, I think.

```
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(serverUri);

//If you need to use network credentials
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpUsername, ftpPassword); 
//additionally, if you want to use the current user's network credentials, just use:
//System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials

request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DeleteFile;
FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
Console.WriteLine("Delete status: {0}", response.StatusDescription);  
response.Close();
```

Answer (score 16):

```
public static bool DeleteFileOnFtpServer(Uri serverUri, string ftpUsername, string ftpPassword)
{
    try
    {
        // The serverUri parameter should use the ftp:// scheme.
        // It contains the name of the server file that is to be deleted.
        // Example: ftp://contoso.com/someFile.txt.
        // 

        if (serverUri.Scheme != Uri.UriSchemeFtp)
        {
            return false;
        }
        // Get the object used to communicate with the server.
        FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(serverUri);
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpUsername, ftpPassword);
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DeleteFile;

        FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        //Console.WriteLine("Delete status: {0}", response.StatusDescription);
        response.Close();
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
    }            
}
```

Usage:

```
DeleteFileOnFtpServer(new Uri (toDelFname), user,pass);
```

Comment: I am getting this error "The requested URI is invalid for this FTP command." can someone help me out? the uri is working fine when I launching

Answer (score 3):

You should use FtpWebRequest when you need to delete files:

```
// Get the object used to communicate with the server.
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(serverUri);
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DeleteFile;

FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();
Console.WriteLine("Delete status: {0}",response.StatusDescription);  
response.Close();
```

ref: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.aspx

Answer (score 3):

```
public static bool DeleteFileOnServer(Uri serverUri)
{

if (serverUri.Scheme != Uri.UriSchemeFtp)
{
    return false;
}
// Get the object used to communicate with the server.
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(serverUri);
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DeleteFile;

FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();
Console.WriteLine("Delete status: {0}",response.StatusDescription);  
response.Close();
return true;
}
```