# delete Sharepoint file using Script Task

Tags: vb.net, sharepoint, ssis, etl, script-task

I need to delete a Sharepoint file using the Script Task from SSIS. In Visual Basic, I've tried using the `SPListItemCollection` with imports `Microsoft.Sharepoint` but it doesn't recognize the namespace. I didn't find lots of threads on this subject or what I've found wasn't related with script task, so any help will be really appreciated. Many thanks

## Update based on @Hadi answer

Thanks Hadi for your answer. I've given up the idea of using SPListCollection as it seems too complicated. Instead I'm trying to delete the file after it is downloaded from Sharepoint to the local folder. I would need help at the line that actually deletes the file. Here is the code:

```
Public Sub Main()
    Try

        ' get location of local folder 

        Dim dir As DirectoryInfo = New DirectoryInfo(Dts.Variables("DestP").Value.ToString())



        If dir.Exists Then
            ' Create the filename for local storage

            Dim file As FileInfo = New FileInfo(dir.FullName & "\" & Dts.Variables("FileName").Value.ToString())


            If Not file.Exists Then

                ' get the path of the file to download 

                Dim fileUrl As String = Dts.Variables("SHP_URL").Value.ToString()




                If fileUrl.Length <> 0 Then 

                    Dim client As New WebClient()



                    If Left(fileUrl, 4).ToLower() = "http" Then

                        'download the file from SharePoint 

                        client.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(Dts.Variables("$Project::UserN").Value.ToString(), Dts.Variables("$Project::Passw").Value.ToString())

                        client.DownloadFile(fileUrl.ToString() & "/" & Dts.Variables("FileName").Value.ToString(), file.FullName)


                    Else
                        System.IO.File.Copy(fileUrl.ToString() & Dts.Variables("FileName").Value.ToString(), file.FullName)

                    End If
'delete file from Sharepoint

                    client.(fileUrl.ToString() & "/" & Dts.Variables("FileName").Value.ToString(), file.FullName).delete()

                Else

                    Throw New ApplicationException("EncodedAbsUrl variable does not contain a value!")

                End If

            End If

        Else

            Throw New ApplicationException("No ImportFolder!")

        End If

    Catch ex As Exception



        Dts.Events.FireError(0, String.Empty, ex.Message, String.Empty, 0)



        Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Failure


    End Try

    Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you add `Microsoft.Sharepoint.dll` as Reference inside the script task?

Comment: i provided an update, hope that it will works

Comment: next time you should leave a comment on my answer to inform me that you have update the question, i will not be notified when writing it in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Update 1 - Delete using FtpWebRequest

You cannot delete file using `WebClient` class. You can do that using `FtpWebRequest` class. And send a `WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DeleteFile` request as mentioned in the link below:

- [How To Delete a File From FTP Server in C#](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/how-to-delete-a-file-from-ftp-server-in-c-sharp1)

It should work with Sharepoint also.

*Here is the function in VB.NET*

```
Private Function DeleteFile(ByVal fileName As String) As String
    Dim request As FtpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create(fileUrl.ToString() & "/" & fileName), FtpWebRequest)
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DeleteFile
    request.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(Dts.Variables("$Project::UserN").Value.ToString(), Dts.Variables("$Project::Passw").Value.ToString())

    Using response As FtpWebResponse = CType(request.GetResponse(), FtpWebResponse)
        Return response.StatusDescription
    End Using
End Function
```

You should replace the following line:

```
client.(fileUrl.ToString() & "/" & Dts.Variables("FileName").Value.ToString(), file.FullName).delete()
```

With

```
DeleteFile(Dts.Variables("FileName").Value.ToString())
```

Also you may use the following credentials:

```
request.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
```

**References**

- [How to pass credentials to httpwebrequest for accessing SharePoint Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5190196/how-to-pass-credentials-to-httpwebrequest-for-accessing-sharepoint-library)
- [How To Delete a File From FTP Server in C#](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/how-to-delete-a-file-from-ftp-server-in-c-sharp1)
- [Downloading all files in a FTP folder and then deleting them](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/97534/downloading-all-files-in-a-ftp-folder-and-then-deleting-them)
- [Deleting file from FTP in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17617203/deleting-file-from-ftp-in-c-sharp)
- [How To Delete a File From FTP Server in C#](http://www.niteshluharuka.com/how-to-delete-a-file-from-ftp-server-in-c/)

---

## Initial Answer

I was searching for a similar issue from a while, it looks like you cannot delete a Sharepoint file in SSIS using a `File System Task` or `Execute Process Task`, the only way is using a `Script Task`. There are many links online describing this process such as:

- [how to delete or remove only text files from share point in C# or SSIS script?](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/461345/how-to-delete-or-remove-only-text-files-from-share)
- [Fastest way to delete all items with C#](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/39579/fastest-way-to-delete-all-items-with-c)
- [Deleting files programatically](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/d5483618-5faa-49e1-ad65-e3b51223fea9/deleting-files-programatically?forum=sharepointdevelopmentlegacy)
- [Deleting all the items from a large list in SharePoint](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/26542/deleting-all-the-items-from-a-large-list-in-sharepoint)

Concerning the problem that you have mentioned, i think you should make sure that `Microsoft.Sharepoint.dll` is added as a reference inside the Script Task. If so try using `Microsoft.Sharepoint.SPListItemCollection` instead of `SPListItemCollection`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Hadi for your help. 
For me it didn't work with FTPWebResponse. 
It worked with HttpWebRequest. Here is the script:

```
Dim request As System.Net.HttpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create(fileUrl.ToString() & "/" & Dts.Variables("FileName").Value.ToString()), HttpWebRequest)

request.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(Dts.Variables("$Project::UserN").Value.ToString(), Dts.Variables("$Project::Passw").Value.ToString())

request.Method = "DELETE"

Dim response As System.Net.HttpWebResponse = CType(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
```